# FFMPEG exec exit code 126

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

here is my code for FFMPEG

```
$mp3path=realpath("1.mp3");
$cmd = "/usr/include/ffmpeg -i $mp3path -ab 128 /home/swiftfa1/public_html/output.mp3 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $output, $value);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($output); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

and here is my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sh: /usr/include/ffmpeg: Is a directory
)
126
```

I used whereis for ffmpeg path and searched a lot but can't solve my issue. any command returns 126!

Comment: The binary should be `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`, the *folder* `/usr/include/ffmpeg/` should contain headers for development. If you don't have the binaries, make sure you have the right packages installed.

Comment: @IbanCereijo Thanks for your answer. I get the path from `WHEREIS`, find command return null and `'find /usr -name "ffmpeg" ` return the same result as WHEREIS. If I use the ` /usr/bin/ffmpeg ` I get `sh: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory` and it returns 127 INT.

Comment: Do you have the **binary** `ffmpeg` installed in your system? if you installed it via a (`.deb`, `.rpm`, ...) package, check that you have the right package, and if it was via `make install` it should go to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: @IbanCereijo I didn't install. It is in select PHP version section in my shared hosting Cpanel. They allow me to use FFMPEG throw this PHP extension section.

Comment: Wherever this is running, you seem to need the `ffmpeg` binary somewhere. It is most certainly not in `/usr/include/ffmpeg`, in case this answers your original question.

Comment: Thanks, I said to the provider but he said it is programming issue. I hope someone can help me.